# Raphael clickable paths that can run for example fancybox

Tags: raphael

hi i'm working with path in Raphael and i wonder how to make this path clickable and after clicking let fancybox start

my path:

```
paper.path("M172.25,647 L381.75,640.75 L422,641.75 L422,665 L415.75,679.5 L402.75,679.5 L401.25,667 L393.751,665 L363.625,665 L352.005,671.673 L346,673 L338.625,677 L172.25,672.5 Z").attr({"fill":"white", "stroke-width": 0, "fill-opacity": .4}).mouseover(
        function () {
                this.animate({"fill-opacity": .8}, 600);
            }).mouseout(function () {
                this.animate({"fill-opacity": .4}, 600);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mostly there. Just add a .click function and you're done. Try the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/7n77v/)